# How to implement bulk pricing/discounts with Drupal Commerce?

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

I've been trying to find a way using [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) to be able to give discounts on individual item prices based on quantity. For instance:

1-9 units of product A: $1.99 per unit

10-19 units of product A: $1.75 per unit

1-19 units of product B: $2.99 per unit

20-39 units of product B: $2.60 per unit

and so on and so forth. However, I haven't been able to find any documentation or modules to do this. Is there any way to do this with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), or any modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The [Price Table](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_price_table) module should be used in this case. I also used the [tutorial that can be found here.](https://drupalcommerce.org/videos/commerce-module-tuesday/commerce-price-table)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use the [Commerce Discount](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_discount) module. Quote from its community documentation:

> The Discount UI (available under Admin → Commerce → Store → Discounts) allows creating and editing discounts. Each discount consists of two related entities: Commerce Discount and Commerce Discount Offer. The Discount allows you to choose what type of entity this discount this will apply to i.e. "Order Discount" or "Product Discount" (line item). The Commerce Discount Offer denotes the result the discount produces. The module provides 4 discount offers out of the box.

Comment: That doesn't work. I set up a discount, and it just applies it to the cart, not the items themselves. For instance, I set up a discount on product A like above. I add 10 units of product A to the cart, and it only takes 24 cents off of the entire order, instead of off of the unit price. This is not acceptable behaviour.